# Getting all contents from canvas

Tags: html, dom, html5-canvas

In HTML5 canvas, is there any way to get all drawings as an array or any json object? I know that canvas does raster based drawing, but is there any way that if I have a canvas already containing some rectangles, circles and text, and I will get all information about coordinates of all the drawings on the canvas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you tried anything so far ??. have you done any googling

Comment: Yes, I tried googling, we can get all pixel information if we want, but I couldn't find anything that gives me objects inside canvas.

Comment: You can export whatever in the canvas to dataURI, this can be imported to another canvas also. did you try that ?

Comment: @AkhilAravind that doesn't give me anything about the content in the canvas. I want the canvas shapes coordinates. In HTML5, SVG is another option for drawing, which provides object for each shape in dom itself. But I want similar result in case of canvas.

Comment: you want to export canvas image to svg ? or get the content of canvas and show that in another canvas. what really you need to achieve

Comment: I want the content of canvas (rectangle, circles or text) in the form of object, (it can be an array or json object).

Comment: I would like to know how do you draw the shapes on the canvas. Are your canvas shapes drawn by the user? Many times to draw the shapes on the canvas you use an array of objects. Is this your case? In other occasions you have some sort of function that picks a random point on the canvas and draw a shape in that point. Is this your case? Can you give some details?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using websockets with Node.js, Express, Socket.io. 
Here's an example for a collaborative drawing canvas : http://code-and.coffee/post/2015/collaborative-drawing-canvas-node-websocket/

I'm not sure it's exactly what you are looking for, but Socket.io does store all drawings points in an array. In the linked example, see `var line_history = []` in the `server.js` file. It can then push to it and emit from it. You can probably tweak the code and adapt it to your needs.

Hope it helps!